# Integrate InviteReferrals program in Android app

Tags: android, android-studio, invite, referrals

I am new to this InviteReferrals program and I have no much information about how it works. I read the official documentation of InviteReferrals program and tried to integrate its SDK in Android app but I am getting below error message:

```
invitereferrals invite: Campaign rule not available
```

I tried to search the issue on SO but didn't find anything for this issue.

As the official document said, I added the below code in manifest file:

```
<meta-data
            android:name="invitereferrals_bid"
            android:value="xxxxx" /> 

        <meta-data
            android:name="invitereferrals_bid_e"
            android:value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
```

xxxxx values are my actual values.

Also, I initialized its SDK correctly using below line of code:

```
// Initialize InviteReferral SDK
        InviteReferralsApi.getInstance(this).initialize(this.getIntent().getData());
```

When to send invite to user, I used the below line of code:

```
InviteReferralsApi.getInstance(this).inline_btn(1);
InviteReferralsApi.getInstance(this).invite("rule1");
```

But I see no referral dialog/message but I get the above mentioned error message in logs.

If anyone has integrated this referral program then kindly let me know when I am doing wrong or what to do to make it work in Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need not to call `invite("rule1")` method for that. Call only:-

InviteReferralsApi.getInstance(this).inline_btn(CAMPAIGN_ID);

where `CAMPAIGN_ID` is your campaign id that you have created in the `InviteReferrals` dashboard.

You can submit your query on Support Ticket on `InviteReferrals` official site for better and faster replies.

Comment: This solution worked for me, thanks a lot. :)
But I've a doubt. Do I need to update CAMPAIGN_ID in app each time when marketing team adds a new campaign? Or there is another way to use CAMPAIGN_ID dynamically?

Comment: You can pass 0 as default campaign id in:- 

InviteReferralsApi.getInstance(this).inline_btn(CAMPAIGN_ID);

and you can change the default campaign from invitereferrals panel